# Pandas transpose dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have have this df, where 'Player' is the index:

```
             Points
Player            
Cássio          0.0
Cássio          0.0
John            0.0
John            2.3
```

How do I transpose it in order to achieve this:

```
         1    2   
Cássio  0.0 0.0 
John    0.0 2.3
...
```

---

df.T gives me:

```
           0       1      3     4          
Player  Cássio  Cássio   John   John ....
Points        0       0     0   2.3
```

But I need Player as index, and not repeated many times.

Comment: `df.T` didn't work for you?

Comment: no because it repeats Player name n times as columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```py
# Turn the index into a column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Declare a column that gives you an inner row id for each player
df['col'] = df.groupby('Player').cumcount()
# Turn your data from long to wide format
df = df.pivot(index='Player', columns='col', values='Points')
# Results looks like this
print(df)

col       0    1
Player          
cassio  0.0  0.0
jon     0.0  2.3
```

After this, you may want to reset the index again and rename your columns however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add one more level of index and unstack:

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby('Player').cumcount())
   .set_index('col', append=True)
   ['Points'].unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
col       0    1    2    3    4
Player                         
Cássio  0.0  0.0  4.7  8.6 -2.1
```

Comment: Yes, the command above returns a new dataframe. You need to assign it to something. Also my code works with your updated sample data.